# Binary Data To Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, binary

Among all the encodings available here http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html
which one is the one I should use for decoding binary data into unicode without it becoming corrupted when I encode it back to string?

I've used raw_unicode_data and it doesn't work.

Example: I upload picture in a POST (but not as file attachment). Django converts POST data to unicode using utf-8. However when converting back from unicode to string (again using utf-8), data becomes corrupted. I used raw_unicode_data and the same happened (though only a few bytes this time). Which encoding should I use so that the decode and encode steps don't corrupt the data.

Comment: "binary data"?  Please define what you mean, provide an example, and -- perhaps, even provide the code that you use to read, retrieve or build this thing.

Comment: The example seems not credible. bytes_representing_a_picture.decode('utf8') is 99.9% guaranteed to fail -- unless of course if Django uses the 'ignore' or 'replace' options (aarrgghh)

Comment: As the answers says, binary data is not text with encoding, then I find out the reason why django can get unicode without raising exceptions is because he use `.decode(default_encoding, 'replace')` to decode the binary data, so, that unicode is meaningless and useless too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Binary data" is not text, therefore converting it to a `unicode` is meaningless. If there is text embedded in the binary data then extract it first and decode using the encoding given in the specification for the data format.

Comment: Binary data can mean anything.  It could be `bytes` from which Unicode can be decoded.

Comment: @S.Lott: If the extraction process is just using the whole thing as-is then so be it. But I stand by my answer.

Comment: You should stand by your answer.  However, you could also consider extending it to cover the most common case of getting binary data from a file.

Comment: Your answer makes complete sense to me. I'm in a Python context, i guess binary can be interpreted as data that does not "follow an encoding", so it's meaningless to decoded into unicode.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to post binary data use the base64 encoding.

http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html

Answer (score 1):

As others have already stated, your question isn't particularly clear. If you are wanting to funnel binary data through a text channel (such as POST), then `base64` is the right format to use with appropriate data transformation operations in the client and the server (binary data -> base64 text -> pass over text channel -> base64 text -> binary data).

Alternatively, if you are wanting to tolerate improperly encoded text (e.g. as Python 3 tries to do for some interfaces such as file paths and environment variables), then Python 3.1 and later offer the `surrogatescape` error handler, which will convert invalid values into a format that isn't valid readable text, but allows the original binary data to be faithfully recreated when encoding back to bytes.

Comment: The problem is not that POST is a text channel because it isn't. Indeed the server will eat everything up to Content-Length without complaining. I guess the problem the OP is facing it that he is trying to upload binary in a POST **field** and the fields parser (mod_wsgi or Django or whatever) is choking when it finds an ampersand in the binary. As you and I suggested base64 should solve it.